# Natural Color Mixing in Processing

Tags: image, image-processing, colors, processing

I am trying to naturally mix green tint on one photo (elephant) and red tint on another photo (ship) by placing the two opaque and tinted photos on top of one another. While both photos appear with equal prominence, when the program is run and both colors can be observed, the red tint (because it is the last tint applied) is more dominant and there is no discernable yellow color in the image no matter which tint is applied first. If anyone knows how to naturally mix colors in processing I would love to hear your advice. I also do not want to simply apply a yellow tint as the last tint. Thanks!

```java
PImage elephant;
PImage ship;
void setup(){
   size(695,473);
   elephant = loadImage("elephantRider.png");
   ship = loadImage("ship.jpg");
   ship.filter(OPAQUE);
   elephant.filter(OPAQUE);
}
void draw(){
   background(255);
   tint(0,255,0, 127);
   image(elephant, 0,0);
   tint(255,0,0,127);
   image(ship, 0,0); 
}
```

Comment: You might want to look into using the `blendMode()` function. More info can be found in [the reference](https://processing.org/reference/blendMode_.html). Can you please provide a link to the images you're using? Without them, we can't run your code.

Comment: Did you ever get this figured out?

Answer (score 0):

Think of Processing as painting. What you're doing now is a little bit like drawing one color to the screen, and then drawing another color on top of the first color.

Instead, what you want to do is mix the two colors together **before** you draw the result to the screen. Think of this as mixing two paints together to make a new color.

You can do this by taking the average of the two colors, something like this:

```
PImage img;

void setup() {
  size(695, 473);
  img = loadImage("image.jpg");
}

void draw() {
  background(255);

  //green
  tint(0, 255, 0, 127);
  image(img, width/2, height/2, 50, 50);

  float blendedRed = (0 + 255) / 2;
  float blendedGreen = (255 + 0) / 2;
  float blendedBlue = (0 + 0) / 2;

  // blended
  tint(blendedRed, blendedGreen, blendedBlue, 127);
  image(img, mouseX, mouseY, 50, 50);
}
```

This example is a little contrived because the averages are pretty trivial, but this approach should work for any color.

If you want something more advanced, note that **color averaging** is a pretty advanced topic. Googling "color averaging" is probably a good start.